# Using Google App Scripts to share documents

Tags: google-apps-script

I have so many documents that I need to manage due to the amount of people that have access to them, and when someone needs to be added or removed, it can become a real pain and time consumer.

I'm curious, is there a script that you can set across multiple documents that give edit or view access.

I'm aware that there is this, "addEditor(emailAddress)", but from what I have gathered, you have to do a script for each document which defeats the purpose of productivity.

Basically, I need one script that gives access to a particular set of documents, and when I need someone removed, i just delete their name and run the script and removes edit/view access from those documents.

Ax example of a script, or rather what I'm trying to achieve. (Not actually a script):

//Human Resources//

addEditor(emailAddress) to BBM1 - Membership Tracker, "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gb8T1K74cRR_6qSyByqrtiphujrchceLP_QsMunoras/edit#gid=0"

//Administrator//

addEditor(emailAddress) to BBM1 - Membership Tracker, "https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gb8T1K74cRR_6qSyByqrtiphujrchceLP_QsMunoras/edit#gid=0"

//Moderator//

addViewer(emailAddress) to BBM1 - Membership Tracker, "docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gb8T1K74cRR_6qSyByqrtiphujrchceLP_QsMunoras/edit#gid=0"

So basically, I can just add emails to that, run the script, and it gives them edit access. But, I just don't know how to create a script that actually works for that and also to have a script across multiple documents.

Many Thanks,

Shaun.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look on [folder api](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder). You can put all those files into a folder, and then everytime you run the script you can loop through all files in the folder and set correct permissions.

Example (untested):

```
var folderName = "My auto-managed documents";

var folderIterator = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(folderName);

while (folderIterator.hasNext()) {
    var folder = folderIterator.next();
    var fileIterator = folder.getFiles();

    while (fileIterator.hasNext()) {
        var file = fileIterator.next();

        // Do things with the file:
        // file.addEditor('my-email@example.com');
    }
}
```

Comment: I still don't understand how this would work though. You need Google Class DriveApp which is confusing me xD